# How to get the file creation date/time in xfs

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, rhel7

I am able to get the file creation date/time using `debugfs` command in ext file system but how to check/get the same in XFS file system.

Comment: [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40093/74329)

Comment: EXT4 is showing the crtime from `debugfs` command. And I am looking for the same in xfs.

Comment: Follow the link and take a look at the comment.

Comment: [xfs v5 supports it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705158)

Answer (score 10):

> XFS does not support creation time. It just has the regular atime,
>   mtime and ctime. There are no plans that I've heard to support it

Source: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.xfs.general/20629